# list in View does not update when the Model changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mvvm, knockout.js

I am trying to build a MVVM using knockout.js. The idea is that the script in **$(document).ready(function() {...}** adds a new item **model.addElement("value");** - "value" to the model every 3 seconds and that should be shown in HTML. Alhough in console output you can see that model is changing and elements are pushed to the **items** list, the HTML stays the same.

At the same time if I uncomment **self.items.push($('#new_item').val());** line - the HTML page will be changing every time the element is added to the model.

Please, help me to understand what am I doing wrong, why cannot i pass this "value" string through the **model.addElement("value");** line?

```js
// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
var ListsViewModel = function(item) {
  var self = this;
  self.item = item;

  self.items = ko.observableArray(["First", "Second", "Third"]);

  self.addElement = function(item) {
    self.items().push(item);
    //self.items.push($('#new_item').val()); //--> uncomment for adding element with a button click
  }

};
var model = new ListsViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("one"));

$(document).ready(function() {
  //comment this if you want add elements only when you click on button
  setInterval(function() {
    model.addElement("value");
    console.log(model.items());
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title>Updating list to the server (automatically)</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="one">
    <h1>Records:</h1>

    <div class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: items">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-bind="text: $data"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="new_item">Item name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_item">
    </div>

    <form>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Add element" data-bind="click: addElement">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="static/js/viewModel.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

**UPD:**
Maybe I have made it unclear, what I wanted was that every 3 seconds new values are added to the model and this change is shown on view (HTML).
I achieved it changing **self.items().push(item);** to **self.items.push(item);**, as @user3297291 suggested. 
Here is the final version of the code which works exactly as I wanted:

```js
// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
var ListsViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.items = ko.observableArray(["First", "Second", "Third"]);
  //self.item = ko.observable("");

  self.addElement = function(item) {
    self.items.push(item);
  }

};
var model = new ListsViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("one"));

$(document).ready(function() {
  //comment this if you want add elements only when you click on button
  setInterval(function() {
    model.addElement("value");
    console.log(model.items());
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

  <title>Updating list to the server (automatically)</title>


</head>

<body>
  <div id="one">
    <h1>Records:</h1>

    <div class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: items">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-bind="text: $data"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="static/js/viewModel.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some minor error fixes that make your snippet work:

- Don't push to the array *inside* `self.items`, since knockout won't be able to notice its contents changed. Push to the `observableArray` directly: `self.items.push` instead of `self.items().push`
- Make `self.item` observable so you can bind its value to the text input: `self.item = ko.observable("")`
- Use the `value` binding to sync `self.item` and  `<input/>.value`: `<input data-bind="value: item">`
- `addElement` doesn't receive an item, it receives an event and the current binding context. Instead, you can retrieve the text box' value using `self.item()`, push it, and clear it using `self.item("")`

When working with knockout, you set the rule to not touch the DOM any other ways except via knockout bindings. Whenever you use jQuery to set or retrieve values, the first question you should ask is "what knockout binding can I use instead".

The fixed version:

```js
// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
var ListsViewModel = function(item) {
  var self = this;
  self.item = ko.observable("");

  self.items = ko.observableArray(["First", "Second", "Third"]);

  self.addElement = function() {
    self.items.push(self.item());
    self.item("");
  }

};
var model = new ListsViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("one"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title>Updating list to the server (automatically)</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="one">
    <h1>Records:</h1>

    <div class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: items">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-bind="text: $data"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="new_item">Item name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_item" data-bind="value: item">
    </div>

    <form>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Add element" data-bind="click: addElement">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="static/js/viewModel.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: May I ask you, how did you do this "Show code snippet"?

Comment: When editing the snippet, there's a checkbox on the left for "Hide snippet by default" that you can tick. This checkbox setting is also included in the markup header that gets inserted in your post:  `hide: true` (the default value is `false`)